# how to upload multi images of a single product

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I'm confused about how to upload a lot of images to a single product like

someone wants to publish a product and chose images of it how I can do that using PHP and MySQL

or if there is another way

for example, I want to create a website where anyone can publish a car with its information and photos

is it possible to insert a lot of image links into a single column in MySQL

I want to use drag and drop for uploading them

[image]

Comment: `is it possible to insert a lot of image links into a single column`...yes, a link is just text. But it's usually a bad idea to denormalise your data structure like that. The proper way would be to have a second table where you can list each image in a separate table row, with a link back to its related product via an ID in another column of the image table, as a foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

  $countfiles = count($_FILES['file']['name']);
  for($i=0;$i<$countfiles;$i++){
    $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'][$i];
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i],'upload/'.$filename);
  }
}
```

for the drag and drop you can use JS [this](https://artisansweb.net/drag-drop-file-upload-using-javascript-php/) could help you